# Complexity computational difference between O(N+m) and O(NM)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

In the algorithm below I cannot understand why the complexity is O(N+M),as calculated by codility.com examination tool, instead of be O(NM). I suppose it is O(NM) because of the two iteration one nested to the other one.

```
function solution($N, $A) {
// write your code in PHP7.0
$counter=[];
$max=0;

foreach($A as $value){
    if($value >= 1 && $value <= $N){
        isset($counter[$value-1]) ? $counter[$value-1]++ : $counter[$value-1] = 1;
        if($counter[$value-1] > $max){
            $max = $counter[$value-1];

            }
        }
    if($value == $N+1){
        for($i = 0; $i<$N; $i++){
            $counter[$i]=$max;
            }
        }
    }
return $counter;
}
```

Since I have not really understood the differences between the two complexities, can anybody give me two simple algorithms showing the two complexities?

Comment: The running time looks linear to me, depending on the number of entries in the `$A` array.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If all values of `$A` are equal to `$N + 1`, it will be O(N*M) if "M" is the size of the array. Right?

Comment: @Kusalananda: That looks right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all values in `A` array are equal to `N+1`, then `counter` array will be filled `M=Length(A)` times, so the worst case is `O(N*M)`, if there are no special limitations on `A` contents.